# Alpakka JMS request/response with temporary queues - possible out of the box?

Tags: akka, jms, alpakka

Thinking of migrating some JMS-based legacy to Alpakka, one of widely used patterns in the code is request/response with temporary queue (JMSReplyTo).
Is it possible with Alpakka out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Alpakka's JMS module does support `JMSReplyTo`. An example from the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/1.0.0/jms/producer.html#setting-jms-message-header-attributes):

```scala
val msgsIn = (1 to 10).toList.map { n =>
  JmsTextMessage(n.toString)
    .withHeader(JmsType("type"))
    .withHeader(JmsCorrelationId("correlationId"))
    .withHeader(JmsReplyTo.queue("test-reply")) // <---
    .withHeader(JmsTimeToLive(FiniteDuration(999, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
    .withHeader(JmsPriority(2))
    .withHeader(JmsDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, but this would be a non-temporary queue. Temporary queues have a lifetime linked to a connection they are created in. And the connection used by the alpakka JMS stream is encapsulalted in the stream. So I guess the answer is a "no".